# Understanding Protractor and WebDriverJS control flow

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, webdriverjs

Can someone help me understand how WebDriverJS/Protractor works in this case?

```
function MyPageObject(buttonElementFinder) {
  this.getButtonByIndex = function(index) {
    return {
      myButton: buttonElementFinder.get(index)
    }
  }
}

1. describe('My button', function() {
2. 
3.   it('should contain the text foo', function() {
4.     var myElementFinder = element.all(by.css('.foo'));
5.     var pageObject = new MyPageObject(myElementFinder);
6.     var button = pageObject.getButtonByIndex(0);
7.     expect(button.text()).toBe('foo');
8.  });
9. 
10. });
```

Does the WebDriverJS control flow have an action added to it on line 6 because of the `.get` method of `ElementFinder`s?

I presume the `expect` also adds another item to the control flow too on line 7?

**Edit: I have update the code to use `element.all`.**

Comment: What is the `get()` method on `ElementFinder` called for? I don't recall this method exists on an `ElementFinder`. Thanks.

Comment: This line may be of use? https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/6ebc4c3f8b557a56e53e0a1622d1b44b59f5bc04/lib/element.js#L247

Comment: Yeah, but this is `ElementArrayFinder` (the result of `element.all()`).

Comment: Ok, I have update the code to use `element.all`. The omission was an error in converting my actual code to something pared down for this question.

Answer (score 3):

```
var myElementFinder = element.all(by.css('.foo'));
```

myElementFinder is a ElementArrayFinder and is simply an object. Nothing async is happening here.

```
var pageObject = new MyPageObject(myElementFinder);
```

Obvious.

```
var button = pageObject.getButtonByIndex(0);
```

This will return an ElementFinder from buttonElementFinder.get. Nothing async is happening here.

```
expect(button.text()).toBe('foo');
```

`button.text()` returns a promise from `Webdriver.schedule`, which in turn is using the control flow which is retrieved using `webdriver.promise.controlFlow()`, which exposes an execute function.